# Create a WCF service to communicate with JQuery through JSON

Tags: json, jquery, wcf

I have a bog standard **html** page. 
All I want to do is :

- use **JQuery** on that page to send **JSON** requests to a WCF service
- retrieve **JSON** back.

That's it.

I have the html page and JQuery written, no problem.

---

However, I can't find one tutorial that works.  All the ones I've found have many conflicting parts to do with behaviors, editing the svc file with a Factory attribute, etc.

Can someone please point me to a bog standard tutorial / example that ACTUALLY works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/default.aspx) has a pretty good resource for this:

- [Query AJAX call to a WCF REST Service](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/324917.aspx)

More importantly, he has a full sample project he uses in his DevConnection talks here:

- [Updated jQuery and WCF 3.5 JSON Samples posted](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/400990.aspx)

I always find using a full blown project I can fire up in Visual Studio is a much better resource than any walk through... hopefully the same is true for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another quick creation of WCF service is using *.svc like
   `<%@ServiceHost language=c# Service="Microsoft.Samples.MyWCFService" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.MyWebServiceHostFactory" %>`

This does not require you to have any configuration in your `web.config` file and this Factory automatically instantiates your service and as this service runs under the same web-app process thread, it shares the Session with your asp web-application.